# ORA-00955 error in oracle, what do i change to resolve this

Tags: oracle

here is my sql statement, all the names of objects are different and i haven't executed before.

```
        create table customer(
             custno varchar(5) constraint custno not null,
             custname varchar(20) constraint custname not null,
             address varchar(25) constraint custadd not null,
             internal char(1) constraint custinternal not null, 
             contact varchar(20) constraint custcontact not null,
             phone integer constraint custph not null,
             city varchar(10) constraint custcty not null,
             state char(2) constraint state not null,
             zip integer constraint custzip not null,

             constraint pkcust primary key(custno)
               );


             create table facility(
                facno varchar(5) constraint facno not null,
                facname varchar(20) constraint facname not null,
                constraint PKfac primary key(facno));
```

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

It doesn't have to be a table itself - could be **constraint** name as well. What is it? Can't tell, but - if you execute those commands in SQL*Plus, it'll point to the culprit. For example:

```
SQL> create table customer (custno varchar2(5) constraint custno not null);

Table created.

SQL> create table facility (facno varchar2(5) constraint custno not null);
create table facility (facno varchar2(5) constraint custno not null)
                                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint


SQL>
```

See the asterisk? Points to exact error point (I named two constraints with the same name).

Comment: thanks, i guess i have to do proper  research about the protocols!!

Answer (score 1):

ORA-00955 Clearly indicates that the object with the same name already exists in your schema.

You can find the already existing object having the same name which you want to give to your object using the metadata views as follows:

```
-- For tables:

SELECT *
  FROM USER_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN (
    'FACILITY',
    'CUSTOMER'
);

-- for constarints
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (
    'PKFAC',
    'FACNAME',
    'FACNO',
    'PKCUST',
    'CUSTZIP',
    'STATE',
    'CUSTCTY',
    'CUSTPH',
    'CUSTCONTACT',
    'CUSTINTERNAL',
    'CUSTADD',
    'CUSTNAME',
    'CUSTNO'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

The exception is self-explanatory, you are using an identifier for an object in the database and that identifier already exists to uniquely identify another object (in the same schema).

For example, you may have a table identified by the name `state` and you are trying to create a constraint with the identifier `state`.

Other answers have dealt with where to find the error. Instead, I'll look at the root cause of the issue and that is a lack of naming policy.

When you name a table, typical naming conventions are to give it a descriptive name and either always make it a singular article (i.e. `customer` or `facility`) or plural (i.e. `customers` or `facilities`) and to be consistent. You've used the singular so this is fine.

When you name a column, again, give it a descriptive name; don't use abbreviations unless you are forced to by a character limit (and if you do then you can add a comment on the column giving the full details); and you don't need to include the table name in the column name as this is redundant information (and extra characters for a developer to type each time you want to use the column).

When you name a constraint, again, give it a descriptive name that identifies where and what it refers to. Often this will involve including:

- the type of constraint (since one column of a table could have several constraints);
- the table name (since there could be multiple tables which each have the same column name); and
- the column name (since there could be multiple constraints of the same type within the same table on different columns).

Some common formulations for a constraint name would be `tablename_columnname_(pk|fk|u|nn|chk)` or `(pk|fk|u|nn|chk)_tablename_columnname` (depending on whether you want have the table name or the constraint type as the primary criteria for ordering constraints when you search for them). But whatever naming convention you use you should make sure you apply it consistently across the database.

Depending on what naming convention you pick, your code could be:

```sql
create table customer(
  customer_no varchar2(5)
              constraint customer_customer_no_nn not null
              constraint customer_customer_no_pk primary key,
  name        varchar2(20)
              constraint customer_name_nn not null,
  address     varchar2(25)
              constraint customer_address_nn not null,
  internal    char(1)
              constraint customer_internal_nn not null
              constraint customer_internal_ck CHECK ( internal IN ( 'Y', 'N' ) ), 
  contact     varchar2(20)
              constraint customer_contact_nn not null,
  phone       integer
              constraint customer_phone_nn not null,
  city        varchar2(10)
              constraint customer_city_nn not null,
  state       char(2)
              constraint customer_state_nn not null,
  zip         integer
              constraint customer_zip_nn not null
);

create table facility(
  facility_no varchar2(5)
              constraint facility_facility_no_nn not null
              constraint facility_facility_no_pk primary key,
  name        varchar2(20)
              constraint facility_name_nn not null
);
```

*(As an aside, using `INTEGER` as the type for `phone` may seem natural as it is numeric data but if the phone number has leading zeroes then these would be stripped off and you may end up with an invalid phone number. Similarly, `zip` may not always be a numeric value when you are dealing with international customers and their country uses an alpha-numeric "zip" code; but if you will only ever deal with customers in one country then this may be acceptable.)*

Comment: thank you! that is very profound, will be making use of this new gained knowledge.